# How to write html code with blade commands in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on laravel project for the first time and i am stuck here with display table.
I just copy and paste one code from google.

```
    @extends('layout/template')
    @section('content')
     <h1>Peru BookStore</h1>
     <a href="{{url('/books/create')}}" class="btn btn-success">Create Book</a>
     <hr>
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
         <tr class="bg-info">
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>ISBN</th>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Author</th>
             <th>Publisher</th>
             <th>Thumbs</th>
             <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              @foreach ($books as $book)
             <tr>
                 <td>{{ $book->id }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->isbn }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->author }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->publisher }}</td>
                 <td><img src="{{asset('img/'.$book->image.'.jpg')}}" height="35" width="30"></td>
                 <td><a href="{{url('books',$book->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{{route('books.edit',$book->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a></td>
                 <td>
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['books.destroy', $book->id]]) !!}    
                 {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                     {!! Form::close() !!}
                 </td>
             </tr>
         @endforeach 

     </tbody>

 </table>
@endsection
```

> I am using this code and problem is my blade commands are visible in
>   webpage. I hear that there is no need to use php tags if i am using
>   blade.php. whats wrong with my code please help me with the same.

Comment: - if you don't write 'blade' with the name of file then the blade commands won't be executed, e.g if you have index.php page, than rename it to  index.blade.php

Comment: i used blade.php

Comment: not only  blade.php, the file must have it own name like index or something eg abc.blade.php  OR index.blade.php

Comment: ya bro its index.blade.php only http://georgehk.blogspot.in/2015/04/crud-operations-in-laravel-5-with-mysql.html i refer this link to create crud operations